# how to handle multiple notifications

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm writing an application based on the notifications, alerts and I'm storing data into `SQLite` database. For example, name and time are of type  `String`. I use `AlarmManager`, however, as the Act notification on hour 10 and 13 is only at 10 gets the notification, how to do that all the notifications were supported?

Comment: Paste your code what you did. And explain what you want to achieve

Comment: add some code to your question